# How to send interface as a parameter to HTTP get request in angular services

Tags: angular, service, http-get

Having difficulty in passing the interface as a parameter for HTTP get request

sample.service.ts

```
 export interface Product{
    Id:any;
    product : any;
   }

public getProduct(item:Product): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.get('/api/getproducts', item);
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        console.log('display data==>', data);
          return data;
      })
    );
    return request;
  }
```

sample.component.ts

```
 this.ps.getProduct(this.product).subscribe(
      data => {
               console.log("results",data.results)
             });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Pass your params using `HttpParams` like below:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('header', 'value');
const params = new HttpParams().append('Id', item.ID);
const params = new HttpParams().append('product', item.product);
this.http.get('url', {headers, params});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder, .append(), dint append the values, so I used .set(), its working perfectly now.